# generic function to create an array of nested objects from a single object of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming

This is a very specific problem but I have an object with arrays:

```
let rawData = {
    one: ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"],
    two: [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
    three: [1,4,9,3,9,7,6,5,5]
  }
```

and I want to write a generic function that will create a set of nested objects based on the first array (here a, but I'd like to make this function not dependent on a specific key.

In my first try I wrote a function that parses this into an array of objects:

```
dataframe_for_plot = (data) => {
  var length
  var names = []
  for (var name in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(name))
            names.push(name);
        length = rawData[name].length;
  }

    var results = [];
    var item;
    for (var row = 0; row < length; row++) {
        item = {};
        for (var col = 0; col < names.length; col++) {
            item[names[col]] = data[names[col]][row];
        }
        results.push(item);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Which yeilds

```
dataframe_for_plot(rawData)
```

```
[
  {one: "a", two: 1, three: 1},
  {one: "a", two: 2, three: 4},
  {one: "a", two: 3, three: 9},
  {one: "b", two: 1, three: 3},
  {one: "b", two: 2, three: 9},
  {one: "b", two: 3, three: 7},
  {one: "c", two: 1, three: 6},
  {one: "c", two: 2, three: 5},
  {one: "c", two: 3, three: 5},
]
```

But I want to build on this function to get my desired output where the first key is used to create objects based on the unique number of that key (3 in this case), and a new `value` key is created to contain a nested array of the other keys (`two` and `three` in this case, grouped together by `one`)

```
let desired_output = [
  {
    one:"a",
    values: [
      {two:1, three:1},
      {two:2, three:4},
      {two:3, three:9}
    ],
  },
    {
    one:"b",
    values: [
      {two:1, three:3},
      {two:2, three:9},
      {two:3, three:7}
    ],
  },
    {
    one:"c",
    values: [
      {two:1, three:6},
      {two:2, three:5},
      {two:3, three:5}
    ],
  }
]
```

I think my function is a good start, but I need a little help working on the nested part 2! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the object to an array of entries, and get the 1st item's `key` and `vals`. Reduce the `vals` to a Map. The Map would have a single object for each unique value from the 1st array if values (`one` in your case). Then iterate the array of the other values, take the respective value from each `[key, arr]` pair, and convert them to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`.

Convert the Map values iterator back to an array using `Array.from()`.

```js
const fn = obj => {
  const [[key, vals], ...values] = Object.entries(obj)
  
  return Array.from(vals.reduce((acc, v, i) => {
    if(!acc.has(v)) acc.set(v, { [key]: v, values: [] })
    
    acc.get(v).values.push(Object.fromEntries(
      values.map(([k, arr]) => [k, arr[i]])
    ))
    
    return acc
  }, new Map()).values())
}

const rawData = {
  one: ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"],
  two: [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
  three: [1,4,9,3,9,7,6,5,5]
}

const result = fn(rawData)

console.log(result)
```

If you want to control the order of properties, you can pass an `order` array, and then create the entries manually in the order you've stated:

```js
const fn = (order, obj) => {
  const [[key, vals], ...values] = order.map(key => [key, obj[key]])
  
  return Array.from(vals.reduce((acc, v, i) => {
    if(!acc.has(v)) acc.set(v, { [key]: v, values: [] })
    
    acc.get(v).values.push(Object.fromEntries(
      values.map(([k, arr]) => [k, arr[i]])
    ))
    
    return acc
  }, new Map()).values())
}

const rawData = {
  one: ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"],
  two: [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
  three: [1,4,9,3,9,7,6,5,5]
}

const result = fn(['one', 'three', 'two'], rawData)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Pretty cool, but I think this relies on Object.entries() to produce a language-defined order of [key, value].

Comment: Since ES6, properties in objects have a predictable order. I agree with you that it's better for the user the pass the actual properties (and order he wishes to get), but you can still use it using the entries.

Comment: @danh - see 2nd snippet. I've added an `order` argument to control the order of extracted properties.

Comment: Even cooler, and thanks for the tip re key order.